# Java Spring: POST Request outputs an unexpected 415 Error when passed JSON Object

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am creating an API that receives the following input, and provides the following output. [image]

So I need to have a function for making guesses. I have not had any luck testing my code so far.

When I send a POST (using POSTMan) as such to http://localhost:8080/guess with the body as `{"game":"klubxb", "guess":"a"}`. I have `Content-type` set to `application/json` and the body is `raw` with `{"game":"lmzxmn","guess":"c"}`

This is the response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-28T00:40:29.141+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/guess"
}
```

The function I have defined for making guesses is:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/guess", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public Game makeGuess(@RequestBody Guess gameAndLetter, HttpSession session) throws GameDoesNotExistException, InvalidCharacterException{
        String game = gameAndLetter.getGame();
        String guess = gameAndLetter.getGuess();
        Game g = getGame(game,session);

        String gameId = g.getId();
        if(gameId.equals(game) && guess.length() > 0) {
            boolean correct = compareWords(guess, g);
            if(!correct){
                g.incIncorrect_guesses();
            }
            g.setStatus();
        }
        else{
            if(!gameId.equals(game)) {
                throw new GameDoesNotExistException(game);
            }
            else{
                throw new InvalidCharacterException(guess);
            }
        }
        g = getGame(game,session);

        return g;
    }
```

I receive a NullPointerException from the serverside:

https://pastebin.com/sczmbDri

This is the code for getGame:

```
// Find an existing game
    private Game getGame(String id, HttpSession session) throws GameDoesNotExistException{
        List<Game> games = (List<Game>) session.getAttribute("games");
        Game g = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++){
            g = games.get(i);
            if(g.getId().equals(id)){
                break;
            }
        }
        if (g == null) {
            throw new GameDoesNotExistException(id);
        }
        return g;
    }
```

Comment: What `Content-type` in `Postman` you are setting for your request? Also on server side, what error logs it tells?

Comment: Ah, `Content-type` was set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I'll edit my question with the new error when `Content-type` of `application\json` is used.

Comment: `Game g = getGame(game,session);` - returns `null`

Comment: @J-Alex That can't be returning null, since  inserting `System.out.println(g.getId());
        System.out.println(g.getGuessed_word());` right before the return statement of getGame() prints data from the object.

Comment: @ohbrobig The root of the exception is in the `Game` class hiding somewhere beyond the posted code...

Comment: As @J-Alex mentioned, the error happened at `com.models.Game.setGuessedChars(Game.java:78)`, due to `NullPointerException`.